# Get next value from range after reaching specific multiples

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, hour

I have a range of values `i` iterating through the number of hours in a year (8760) starting at 1. For every hour, the variable `hour` increments by 1 until it reaches 24 where it restarts. The variable `year_day` increments by 1 after every 24 hours is reached. Eg

```
i    hour    year_day
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
...
23    23  1
24    1   2
25    2   2
...
47    24  2
48    1   3
49    2   3
```

I'm struggling to make it so that when `i = 24`, `hour` also is 24 and `year_day` remains at 1. Then when `i` is the next value directly after a multiple is found, the `hour` restarts at 1 and `year_day` increments by 1. In other words, everytime it reaches midnight, the `hour = 24` and `year_day` is still the previous day. Eg

```
i    hour    year_day
23    23  1
24    24  1
25    1   2
...
47    23  2
48    24  2
49    1   3
```

Here is the code:

```
hour = 0
year_day = 1
for i in range(1, 8761):
    hour = hour + 1
    if i % 24 == 0:
        hour = 1
        year_day = year_day + 1
    print(i, hour, year_day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, you just need to start with `hour=1` and print before the if statement. Try the following:

```
hour = 1
year_day = 1
for i in range(1, 8761):
    print(i, hour, year_day)
    hour+=1
    if i % 24 == 0:
        hour = 1
        year_day = year_day + 1
```

Output:

```
...
21 21 1
22 22 1
23 23 1
24 24 1
25 1 2
26 2 2
27 3 2
...
```

Comment: So it was just a logic error on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have used a pandas approach to this question. The code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = list(range(1,50))
df = pd.DataFrame(i, columns=["i"])
df["hours"] = df["i"]%24
df["hours"][df["hours"]==0] = 24
df["days"] = (df["i"]//24.1+1).astype(int)
display(df)
```

The output is:

```
    i   hours   days
0   1   1       1
1   2   2       1
2   3   3       1
3   4   4       1
4   5   5       1
5   6   6       1
6   7   7       1
7   8   8       1
8   9   9       1
9   10  10      1
10  11  11      1
11  12  12      1
12  13  13      1
13  14  14      1
14  15  15      1
15  16  16      1
16  17  17      1
17  18  18      1
18  19  19      1
19  20  20      1
20  21  21      1
21  22  22      1
22  23  23      1
23  24  24      1
24  25  1       2
25  26  2       2
26  27  3       2
27  28  4       2
28  29  5       2
29  30  6       2
30  31  7       2
31  32  8       2
32  33  9       2
33  34  10      2
34  35  11      2
35  36  12      2
36  37  13      2
37  38  14      2
38  39  15      2
39  40  16      2
40  41  17      2
41  42  18      2
42  43  19      2
43  44  20      2
44  45  21      2
45  46  22      2
46  47  23      2
47  48  24      2
48  49  1       3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer using pandas, haven't used this before but I'll start reading up on it!

Answer (score 1):

```
hour = 0
year_day = 1
for i in range(1, 8761):
    if i % 24 == 0:
        hour = 0
        year_day += 1
    hour += 1
    print(i, hour, year_day)
```

Returns:

```
20 20 1
. . .
24 1 2
25 2 2
. . .
46 23 2
47 24 2
48 1 3
```